# How to print the list of running processes, in Windows

Tags: windows, printing, process

What tool should I be using so that I can easily print a list with all the processes that are currently running in Windows?

Or maybe there are some commands I could use. Any suggestions?

Comment: By *print* you mean actually printing on paper?

Comment: Obviously - yes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tasklist` command will output a list of all running processes.  You can redirect it to a text file with `tasklist > filename.txt` and then print that file using Notepad or any other program that handles text files.

Comment: Both are good answers, however the result of this command looks better than the other one, so I will mark this is the best answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ahh yes, Powershell ... Powershell is the wave of the future.  Like most Powershell commands I think you can add format flags to modify the output format (even output it to HTML if you want if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 9):

In PowerShell you could use: `get-process` or `get-wmiobject WIN32_PROCESS`.

Ok, but can PowerShell show more details? More than CMD tasklist?

- `get-process | format-table -property * -autosize`
- `gps | ft * -auto`   (same command, but shorter version)
- `get-wmiobject WIN32_PROCESS | format-table -property * -autosize`
- `gwmi WIN32_PROCESS | ft * -auto`  (same command, but shorter version)

Uh, thats too much detail. Can I select the columns I need?

- `gps | ft name,ID,sessionID,basepriority,priorityClass,path -auto`
- `gwmi WIN32_PROCESS | ft name,processID,priority,CommandLine -auto`

Ah, better. But some columns are truncated. I can avoid this by saving to file, right?

- `gps | ft * -auto | Out-File D:\process-list.txt -Width 4096`
- `gwmi WIN32_PROCESS | ft * -auto | Out-File D:\process-list.txt -Width 4096`

Wonderful. What about printing it directly?

- `gps | ft * -auto | Out-Printer`
- `gwmi WIN32_PROCESS | ft * -auto  | Out-Printer`

Can I also export them as CSV ?

- `gps | select * | Export-Csv D:\process-list.csv`
- `gwmi WIN32_PROCESS | select * | Export-Csv D:\process-list.csv`

Oh thats cool. Can I sort the output by memory or CPU usage?

```
gwmi WIN32_PROCESS | Sort ws -desc | ft name, @{Name="Mem Usage (KB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1kb)}} -auto
gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | sort PercentProcessorTime -desc| ft name, PercentProcessorTime -auto
```

---

All commands are fully explained on [SS64.com](http://ss64.com/ps/) together with some examples and available aliases.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I summarized the basics in a step-by-step tutorial, complete with screenshots and references to useful documentation, here: http://www.7tutorials.com/how-print-list-running-processes-windows-7-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

powerShell

```
Get-Process | Out-File d:\processes.txt
```