# How to copy the data of all of the rows in Task Manager in Windows8?

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe

Currently, you can only select one row, press ctrl+c and then press ctrl +v to excel.

If there is no way to do it from Task Manager, is there some other ways? Such as from cmd.exe.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Related: [How to print the list of running processes, in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/630573/how-to-print-the-list-of-running-processes-in-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press you Windows Key, then type `Powershell` to open a PowerShell session, then type `ps` to get a list of all processes with some standard columns.

To copy the information, use one of the out- cmdlets:

```
ps | Out-Clipboard
```

or

```
ps | Out-File C:\processes.txt
```

to limit the number of processes to show, you can filter:

```
ps | where ProcessName -eq Chrome | Out-Clipboard
```

to show different columns, specify them:

```
ps | where ProcessName -eq Chrome | Select Id, ProcessName, Path | Out-Clipboard
```

to get a list of all available columns you could do:

```
ps | where Id -eq 0 | fl *
```

You can do a lot more filtering, but this should get you started.

cmd.exe is just there for backwards compatibility, PowerShell is much more powerful and if you want to learn to do stuff on the command line, I recommend using PowerShell.

I never tried PowerShell with simplified Chinese, so I don't know how well that works.

Comment: +1 always like to see a scripting solution (especially with powershell)